# Running redcar 0.8.1 on Windows 7 x64

Tags: ruby, windows, jruby, redcar

I am trying to get redcar to run on a windows 7 x64 box but I am getting the following error:

```
Redcar 0.8.1 ( java )
Error loading plugin: <Plugin swt 1.0 depends:[dep(core >0)] 0 files>
  cannot link Java class org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display, probable missing dependency: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM
  c:/devtools/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/builtin/javasupport/java.rb:51:in `method_missing'
  C:/devtools/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redcar-0.8.1/plugins/swt/lib/swt.rb:129
  C:/devtools/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redcar-0.8.1/plugins/swt/lib/swt.rb:31:in `require'
  c:/devtools/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
  C:/devtools/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redcar-0.8.1/lib/plugin_manager/lib/plugin_manager/plugin_definition.rb:41:in `load'
  C:/devtools/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redcar-0.8.1/lib/plugin_manager/lib/plugin_manager/plugin_definition.rb:58:in `log_requires'
  C:/devtools/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redcar-0.8.1/lib/plugin_manager/lib/plugin_manager/plugin_definition.rb:40:in `load'
  C:/devtools/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redcar-0.8.1/lib/plugin_manager/lib/plugin_manager.rb:128:in `load_plugin'
  C:/devtools/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redcar-0.8.1/lib/plugin_manager/lib/plugin_manager.rb:109:in `load'
  C:/devtools/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redcar-0.8.1/lib/redcar.rb:111:in `load_prerequisites'
  C:/devtools/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redcar-0.8.1/lib/redcar.rb:142:in `load_threaded'
  C:/devtools/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redcar-0.8.1/bin/redcar:28
  C:/devtools/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redcar-0.8.1/bin/redcar:19:in `load'
  c:\devtools\jruby-1.5.3\bin\redcar:19
C:/devtools/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redcar-0.8.1/plugins/swt/lib/swt.rb:50:in `show': uninitialized constant Swt::Graphics (NameError)
        from C:/devtools/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redcar-0.8.1/plugins/swt/lib/swt.rb:97:in `create_splash_screen'
        from C:/devtools/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redcar-0.8.1/lib/redcar.rb:168:in `show_splash'
        from C:/devtools/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redcar-0.8.1/bin/redcar:29
        from C:/devtools/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redcar-0.8.1/bin/redcar:19:in `load'
        from c:\devtools\jruby-1.5.3\bin\redcar:19
```

The error seems to indicate a problem with SWT being the 32-bit version. Since eclipse based application run fine on my machine I guess there is something I am missing here.

Steps I used to install redcar:

- download and install jruby (used the 64-bit executable)
- run `jruby -S gem install redcar` to install the redcar gem
- run `redcar install`

I also tried to install from source but with the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redcar doesn't support Win64 yet. Not for any particular reason, we're just getting to it.

If you want to make it work, copy the 64 bit swt jar on top of the `win32.jar` in `~/.redcar/jars`

If that doesn't do the job, get in touch.

Comment: OK I'll try that ASAP and keep you posted. Thanks for the quick reply. Looking forward to getting the textmate goodness on my Windows box!

Comment: Yep, it works. Download the swt.jar from http://www.eclipse.org/swt/ and replace the win32.jar in .redcar/assets/swt/ with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not being cool enough to have Windows 7 I'm afraid I cannot really help you, but I think your best bet would be to ask the guys/girls developing Redcar directly. Feel free to send an email to the Redcar-editor group (redcar-editor@googlegroups.com).

Comment: Yeah I opened a ticket on github already but I'll ping the group too then... And don't worry about being cool, took me years to get there: just hang on ;-) That said I'm not sure it's a windows specific problem but then again I am not really familiar with how SWT bindings work.

Comment: Works fine on my 32bit version of XP. I saw that they released a 8.1 the other which was a fix for windows. No idea if it's related to your problem though :)